# How to perform linear regression on a subset of rows and store trend and correlation value in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, regression, subset

I have this dataframe:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  STATE STATEFP YEAR  GW_ratio SW_ratio
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 AL          1 2000    0.0425    0.958
2 AL          1 2005    0.0474    0.953
3 AL          1 2010    0.0469    0.953
4 AL          1 2015    0.0563    0.944
5 AR          5 2000    0.627     0.373
6 AR          5 2005    0.646     0.354
```

I want to get the trend as a relation between SW_ratio and GW_ratio for each state for each four year period (2000,2005,2010,2015), which you can perform with `lm`. And then I want to store it in the following dataframe:

```
  STATE STATEFP trend
1    AL       1     0
2    AR       5     0
3    AZ       4     0
4    CA       6     0
5    CO       8     0
6    CT       9     0
```

Does anyone know how to perform a regression analysis over a subset of rows in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data is something like this:

```
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(STATE  =rep(c("AL","AR"),each=4),
STATEFP = rep(c(1,5),each=4),
YEAR = rep(c(2000,2005,2010,2015),2),
GW_ratio = runif(8), SW_ratio = runif(8))

head(df)

  STATE STATEFP YEAR  GW_ratio   SW_ratio
1    AL       1 2000 0.5929813 0.43216062
2    AL       1 2005 0.7264811 0.09368152
3    AL       1 2010 0.3704220 0.55577991
4    AL       1 2015 0.5149238 0.59022849
5    AR       5 2000 0.3776632 0.06714114
6    AR       5 2005 0.4183373 0.04754785
```

One way is to pivot it long, and group by the state and the variable, then perform the linear regression:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

df %>% 
pivot_longer(-c(STATE,YEAR,STATEFP)) %>% 
group_by(STATE,STATEFP,name) %>% 
do(augment(lm(value ~ YEAR,data=.)))
```

You get something like this:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 11
# Groups:   STATE, STATEFP, name [4]
   STATE STATEFP name      value  YEAR  .fitted  .resid  .hat  .sigma .cooksd
   <fct>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 AL          1 GW_ratio 0.593   2000  0.640   -0.0468   0.7 0.204    0.347 
 2 AL          1 GW_ratio 0.726   2005  0.581    0.146    0.3 0.137    0.265 
 3 AL          1 GW_ratio 0.370   2010  0.522   -0.151    0.3 0.128    0.286 
 4 AL          1 GW_ratio 0.515   2015  0.463    0.0523   0.7 0.200    0.433 
 5 AL          1 SW_ratio 0.432   2000  0.278    0.155    0.7 0.175    1.69  
 6 AL          1 SW_ratio 0.0937  2005  0.371   -0.277    0.3 0.0146   0.428 
 7 AL          1 SW_ratio 0.556   2010  0.465    0.0910   0.3 0.314    0.0460
 8 AL          1 SW_ratio 0.590   2015  0.558    0.0318   0.7 0.327    0.0715
```

What remains is to pivot it wide again, so here's the complete steps:

```
res = df %>% 
pivot_longer(-c(STATE,YEAR,STATEFP)) %>% 
group_by(STATE,STATEFP,name) %>% 
do(augment(lm(value ~ YEAR,data=.))) %>% 
select(c(STATE,STATEFP,name,YEAR,.fitted)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from=c(name,YEAR),values_from=.fitted)

data.frame(res)
  STATE STATEFP GW_ratio_2000 GW_ratio_2005 GW_ratio_2010 GW_ratio_2015
1    AL       1     0.6397368     0.5807136     0.5216905     0.4626673
2    AR       5     0.3263059     0.3319276     0.3375492     0.3431709
  SW_ratio_2000 SW_ratio_2005 SW_ratio_2010 SW_ratio_2015
1   0.277517333     0.3711475     0.4647777     0.5584079
2  -0.007647359     0.1170041     0.2416555     0.3663070
```

If you just want to keep the slope of GW_ratio vs SW_ratio in each state,, then it will be:

```
df %>% group_by(STATE,STATEFP) %>% do(tidy(lm(GW_ratio ~ SW_ratio,data=.))) %>% filter(term=="SW_ratio")
# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   STATE, STATEFP [2]
  STATE STATEFP term     estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <fct>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 AL          1 SW_ratio   -0.567     0.234    -2.43    0.136
2 AR          5 SW_ratio    0.436     0.810     0.539   0.644
```

Comment: I think I was not very clear in my questioning. What I am looking for is a way to perform a regression on GW_ratio vs SW_ratio over the years, as this ratio is always on the y-1 line I can see how it changes over time. Therefore I want to do a regression over the years and store one single value (which should be the slope) in a table which belongs to the corresponding STATE.

Comment: I am sorry in the example, it is incredibly unclear and still lacking information. why do you have 8 columns then?

Comment: I've updated the question with a frame of how the final output should look like.
I only used the second frame as an example output where I could store the trend. What I want to store in the trend column is the trend of the relation between SW_ratio and GW_ratio in time. I only have data for four years so it will not be a significant trend at all, but I will then filter out the ones with correlation > 0.6, thus maybe adding a correlation column would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the difference between your starting data set and the desired output is only a change in shape from long to wide.

Let's say we have this data (I just copied some AL rows to complete AR):

```
library(tidyverse)
state_info_long <- tibble::tribble(
  ~STATE, ~STATEFP, ~YEAR, ~GW_ratio, ~SW_ratio,
    "AL",       1L, 2000L,    0.0425,     0.958,
    "AL",       1L, 2005L,    0.0474,     0.953,
    "AL",       1L, 2010L,    0.0469,     0.953,
    "AL",       1L, 2015L,    0.0563,     0.944,
    "AR",       5L, 2000L,     0.627,     0.373,
    "AR",       5L, 2005L,     0.646,     0.354,
    "AR",       5L, 2010L,     0.627,     0.373,
    "AR",       5L, 2015L,     0.646,     0.354
  )
```

We could use tidyr to pivot wider to look like your target output:

```
state_info_long %>%
  pivot_wider(c(STATE:STATEFP), names_sep = ".",
              names_from = YEAR, values_from = GW_ratio:SW_ratio)

# A tibble: 2 x 10
  STATE STATEFP GW_ratio.2000 GW_ratio.2005 GW_ratio.2010 GW_ratio.2015 SW_ratio.2000 SW_ratio.2005 SW_ratio.2010 SW_ratio.2015
  <chr>   <int>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 AL          1        0.0425        0.0474        0.0469        0.0563         0.958         0.953         0.953         0.944
2 AR          5        0.627         0.646         0.627         0.646          0.373         0.354         0.373         0.354
```